# Image loading slowly from local store in windows store apps

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I am getting an image(captured photo from camera api) from local store and setting it to src of image element dynamically. The image takes too much time to load is there any workaround for this.

```
     var imgsrc = "ms-appdata:///temp/" + photo.name;
     document.getElementById(htmlid).src = imgsrc;
```

Comment: Are you loading from an SD card?

Comment: How large is the image file you're trying to load? And what is "too much time" in your observations?

Comment: Basically I have created a camera functionality which saves the image to local store and displays it. When I use getthumbnailasync and paint the image its fine. But due to my app limitations as I need to send the URL of the image. Also the image is too large . time is varied. Sometimes 2 minutes and can me more too

Comment: getThumbnailAsync was made specificially to limit the size of an image being loaded, and to draw from image caches on the file system, and thus it performs quite well. When you have a large image, the memory requirements go up dramatically and perhaps that's part of the slowdown. If you have to use a URI, one approach you might take is to automatically make a downsampled copy that's much smaller (i.e. do you own thumbnails), and send the URI to that. Just a thought. Otherwise, if you're just letting the img element load the file, there's not much more you can do.